# Field order in onestepcheckout of Claue Template

Tags: checkout, sorting, magento2.4.4, onestepcheckout

I  use onestepcheckout from claue theme and PostNL address check. As you can see postcode, huisnu and toevoeging are at the bottum of bezorg adres iso after achternaam. How can i move these fields up?

[image: checkout form]

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onestepcheckout module there is a block name: `Your_onestepcheckoutModule/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor` class. And there is one method `public function process($jsLayout)` which you can use by creating plugin and adjust your field location.

```
namespace Your\OnestepcheckoutModule\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'] ='*Set Value movement*';

    return $jsLayout;
}
}
```